# Help with Blackberry development

Tags: java, blackberry, eclipse-plugin

I just installed Eclipse Classic to develop a BB app in Java..
Im following [this steps](http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/javaappdev/javaupdate.jsp) bit im stuck trying to install the BlackBerry Java Plug-in item cause it tells me the plugin requires 'org.eclipse.ui' but I cant figure out how to install that.. Im pretty sure I need to add a repository to the eclispe sites but I cant find the address... anyone care to give me a hand??
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of eclipse are you running?

The BB plugin is compatible with 3.5 only; trying to install on 3.6 will cause these issues.

Also, I would strongly recommend installing throgh the eclipse plugin updater/installer to avoid issues later - the standalone installer doesn't play nicely with updates to the plugin version the last I tried it.

The update URL to use if you go this route is http://www.blackberry.com/go/eclipseUpdate/3.5/java  -- you will also need to register for a blackberry developer account (free) if you decide to go this route: http://na.blackberry.com/eng/developers/  (You will be prompted for login credentials during plugin installation.)